# How to view user script objects in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm newbie in user scripts and attempted to patch some user script in Chrome+Tampermonkey.

On attempts to see variables instead of them I see this error: [image: screenshot]

Script debugging in Tampermonkey settings page is enabled, Tampermonkey extension is selected in the Console tab. Also I cannot view the variables even through the Console (both as `embedcontent` and `this.embedcontent`, however second way returns `null` instead of a error).

What's also need to see and/or edit them in DevTools?

Comment: Devtools shows only those variables that are still defined in the current function context. Also, it won't show those that aren't used after the current execution line. You can use the `scope` panel or double-click the callstack entries to switch execution context ([tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)).

Answer (score -1):

Found that it is semi-possible. Userscript objects (variables) can be accessed via DevTools only on breakpoints, fired near these objects. Otherwise it will not see them.

Comment: There is no concept of value that the debugger could use to determine value that isn't in current stack. Variables in userscript are defined in anonymous function scope. The debugger cannot know that this function is only called once, and this cannot find an unambiguous values.